# appcenter push notification name not shown in notification

Tags: push-notification, visual-studio-app-center

I'm using app center push notification and I'm sending http post request to send push with the api of appcenter push.
when I send push notification with this payload

```
    {
 "notification_content" : {
  "name" : "First Push From App Center",
  "title" : "Push From App Center",
  "body" : "Welcome!",
  "custom_data" : {"key1" : "val1", "key2" : "val2"}
  },
    "notification_target" : {
    "type" : "audiences_target",
    "audiences" : ["a-1", "a-2"]
  }
}
```

url

> https://api.appcenter.ms/v0.1/apps/XXXX/${platform}/push/notifications

I get the notification in my phone but only with title and body and I don't see the name "First Push From App Center"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the notification is not pushed to devices, it's only a name for you to remember what notifications you created when you list them. Name will for example appear in the portal when you list all push notifications you created.

Comment: Can i add heading,title and content to push? I mean to get 3 difference text in push on device?

Comment: Today it's not possible. It would require silent push support (e.g. send only custom data and no notification) and building a custom notification in the app from the silent push with custom data. Unfortunately App Center does not have silent push support.